# UIViewController pass float value to UIView method

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController with a `HandlePan` method:

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];

    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];
        CGFloat panSpeed = (translation.x+translation.y)/2;
        NSLog(@"PanSpeed %f",panSpeed);
        [someview viewPan:panSpeed];
    }

}
```

Then I have a `UIView` called `someview` with the method:

```
- (void) viewPan:(float *)PanAngle {
    NSLog(@"Panning...%@",PanAngle);
}
```

But I am getting a `nil` for `PanAngle`.

What is the proper way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining (getting a reference to) "someview" in the statement [someview viewPan:panSpeed] ?

Comment: in `someview.h`, `- (void) viewPan;`, in VC,`#import "someview.h"`. Then I call the method `[someview viewPan:panSpeed]`.

Answer (score 2):

float isn't an object, so no need for a pointer

```
- (void)viewPan:(float)PanAngle{
    NSLog(@"Panning...%f",PanAngle);
}
```

Comment: I still get a null, not sure why.

Comment: how can a primate type be null? if you are realy passing a float and in your NSLog prints %f and not %@, than you will get at least a 0 or a wild number, but not null :o